# HowTo enable java plugin in CasperJS?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I try to test a site which need java plugin.

With this code

```
casper.test.comment('-> Loading page');
casper.start('http://localhost:8080', function() {
   casper.test.comment('-> Capture : homeURL loaded.png');
   casper.capture('homeURL loaded.png');
});

casper.run(function(){
   this.test.done();
});
```

I have a capture showing that java plug-in is not loaded.

How can I load it?

I also tried this which doesn't works either:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  true,        // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
        loadPlugins: true         // use these settings
    }
})

casper.test.comment('-> Loading page');
casper.start('http://localhost:8080', function() {
   casper.test.comment('-> Capture : homeURL loaded.png');
   casper.capture('homeURL loaded.png');
});

casper.run(function(){
   this.test.done();
   casper.exit();
});
```

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Hi, Is CasperJS just able to work with applet? Otherwise I'll stopo my test with that tool. Best regards, Chris

Answer (score 0):

I did use this, just changed the url to google.com.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  true,        // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
        loadPlugins: true         // use these settings
    }
})
casper.test.comment('-> Loading page');
casper.start('http://google.com', function() {
   casper.test.comment('-> Capture : homeURL loaded.png');
   casper.capture('homeURL loaded.png');
});
casper.run(function(){
   this.test.done();
   casper.exit();
});
 It ran for me ...This is  what I got back
C:\Examples>casperjs  test load.js
Test file: load.js
# -> Loading page
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://google.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://google.com/, type=Other, will
Navigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://google.com/"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2 http://google.com/ (HTTP 407)
# -> Capture : homeURL loaded.png
[debug] [phantom] Capturing page to C:/Examples/homeURL loaded.png
[info] [phantom] Capture saved to C:/Examples/homeURL loaded.png
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/2: done in 242ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 245ms.
```

Comment: Hi divya, I have tried such things on others sites and it works. But my own site use applet for authentification, and I'm not able to launch java plugin to execute it.